# Find a file with a matching string and perform actions on it UNIX

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix

Part1: I have a folder "MyFolder" with multiple subfolders like "new" "old" etc.
I need a UNIX code which will loop through each folder and subfolder and create a copy of the files "abc_MED.txt" which isn't have "_MED.txt"
Eg: abc.txt -> abc_MED.txt -> abc_MED.txt
It shouldn't add everytime abc_MED_MED.txt XX

Part 2: For all files with "_MED.txt" it should add "_2" at the end of first line of the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried this:

```
for file in *.txt
do
if [[  ! -f ${file%*}_MED.txt ]]
then
     cp $file ${file%.*}_MED.txt
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `find`, creating the command with option `-printf` and then, executing with pipe to bash :

`find MyFolder/  -mindepth 1 -type f -not -name '*_MED.txt' -printf 'echo mv %p $(echo %p| sed 's/.txt/_MED.txt/g')\n' | bash | bash`

Second part, add of content

`find MyFolder/  -mindepth 1 -type f -not -name '*_MED.txt' -exec sed -E -i '/$/ a "_2"' {} +`

Comment: find: %pn’: unknown primary or operator

Comment: What if the output from find MyFolder/  -mindepth 1 -type f -not -name '*_MED.txt' -printf`

Comment: Your code does the work just the part one creates file like abc.txt_MED.txt it should be abc_MED.txt...Please help me with the code change , Thanks in tons

Comment: find MyFolder/  -mindepth 1 -type f -not -name '*_MED.txt' -printf 'echo mv %p $(echo %p| sed 's/.txt/_MED.txt/g')\n' | bash | bash

Comment: I tried the below code it replaces the exisiting file with _MED instead of creating a new file and adding _MED.txt into it

Comment: The option -mindepth 1 conflicts with "loop through each folder and subfolder" in the question

Answer (score 2):

This is my bash solution

```
find . -type f -not -name "*_MED*" -exec sed -i '1{s/$/_2/}' {} +
```

**Explanation:**
Find all files (-f) that does not (-not) match (-name) the pattern "*_MED*", for each of them execute the sed command sed -i '1{s/$/_2/}' that add _2 at the end of the line, only once

find . -type f -not -name "*_MED*" -exec sed -i '' '1i\'$'\n''_2' {} +

**EDIT**
Since you are on a mac machine (I didn't know that), the sed command is a bit different, try this one

```
find . -type f -not -name "*_MED*" -exec sed -i '' '1s/$/  _2/' {} \;
```

Comment: sed: 1: "./.DS_Store": invalid command code .Facing this error? and i cant see and copy of file i want to make copy and of file with the end _2.txt and add _2 at the end of created files

Comment: Ok I understood the problem: you are on a MAC system, the sed command is different there, so why do you say UNIX in the title of the question?

Comment: I added the mac syntax of the command, anyway your question is confused

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command, it will search for files ignoring `*_MED.txt`

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.txt" ! -iname "*_MED.txt" \)
```